# PhoneGap - Writing to the iCloud directory?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, icloud

My app is telling me that my iCloud ubiquity container is here:

`file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Library/Mobile%20Documents/.../`

When I try to get the directory with `fileSystem.root.getDirectory`, I error and don't get a `DirectoryEntry`. I tried `window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI`, but that also ends with error.

How do I get an entry for this directory, so that I can write to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a javascript bridge. iCloud has so much setup and error handling that it's not really possible to handle this entirely in javascript without a complex wrapper of some kind.